# How to change significant mark?

Tags: r

When I use `lm` function, the `summary` shows:

```
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

data(mtcars)
fit1 <- lm(mpg~cyl+disp+hp+wt,data=mtcars)
summary(fit1)
```

I want to use `0.01 ***,0.05 **,0.1*,1 ' '`.

```
sink("printCoefmat.R") 
printCoefmat 
sink()
```

I followed [this page](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/04/11/7617.html), add

```
cutpoints = c(0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1),
symbols = c("***", "**", "*", " "))
```

and do some changes about the 'printCoefmat.R' file,
then,I use :

```
source("printCoefmat.R")
```

but it doesn't work.

```
summary(fit1)
```

still shows that:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 40.82854    2.75747  14.807 1.76e-14 ***
cyl         -1.29332    0.65588  -1.972 0.058947 .  
disp         0.01160    0.01173   0.989 0.331386    
hp          -0.02054    0.01215  -1.691 0.102379    
wt          -3.85390    1.01547  -3.795 0.000759 ***
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Residual standard error: 2.513 on 27 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8486,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8262 
F-statistic: 37.84 on 4 and 27 DF,  p-value: 1.061e-10
```

I want to change the output of `lm`:

```
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

into:

```
Signif. codes:  0.01 ‘***’ 0.05 ‘**’ 0.1 ‘*’
```

I want the output like this:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 40.82854    2.75747  14.807 1.76e-14 ***
cyl         -1.29332    0.65588  -1.972 0.058947 *  
disp         0.01160    0.01173   0.989 0.331386    
hp          -0.02054    0.01215  -1.691 0.102379    
wt          -3.85390    1.01547  -3.795 0.000759 ***
Signif. codes:  0.01 ‘***’ 0.05 ‘**’ 0.1 ‘*’
Residual standard error: 2.513 on 27 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8486,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8262 
F-statistic: 37.84 on 4 and 27 DF,  p-value: 1.061e-10
```

Comment: please show us the code you wrote (i.e. how you followed the cited page), and what "doesn't work" -- does nothing change?

Comment: the definition of signif stars is in the examples of `?symnum`

Comment: yes,the signif stars is in `symnum ` functions

Comment: sorry can't answer. you can modifiy this function:  `fixefs <- function(model) {
 #model = lmerMod Object
 S <- summary(model)
 cfs <- S$coefficients #get fixed effects
 p <- ifelse(cfs[ ,ncol(cfs)] < .001, "***", ifelse(cfs[ ,ncol(cfs)] < .01, "**", ifelse(cfs[ ,ncol(cfs)] < .05, "*", "")))
 e <- round(cfs[ ,1], digits=3)
 s <- round(cfs[ ,2], digits=3)
 o <- paste(e, p, " (", s, ") ", sep="")
 print(cbind(rownames(cfs), o))
 write.table(o, "clipboard", sep="\t", quote=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
}`

Comment: @chunjin so _rewrite it_ how you would like it to act, should I explain further?